# ErrorException compact(): Undefined variable: Sep - laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js, laravel-8

please help me
I made a chart, but there is a problem when I want to display the data, why is it compacted?

example code controller :

```
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
            $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $jumlah_user = User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get()->count();

            $data = Verifikasi_tte::join('surat_ttes', 'surat_ttes.id', '=', 'verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.user_id')
                ->join('jenis_surat_ttes', 'jenis_surat_ttes.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.jenis_surat_tte_id')
                ->select('surat_ttes.id','surat_ttes.klasifikasi','surat_ttes.no_surat','surat_ttes.tgl_surat','surat_ttes.created_at',
                'jenis_surat_ttes.nama_jenis_surat','users.name','users.opd_id','verifikasi_ttes.status')
                ->get()->groupBy(function($data){
                return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('M');
            });
    
            $months=[];
            $monthCount=[];
            foreach($data as $month => $values){
                $months[]=$month;
                $monthCount[]=count($values);
            }

            return view('dashboard.admins',  compact('user','jumlah_user', ['data'=>$data,'months'=>$months,'monthCount'=>$monthCount] ));
        }
```

if there is a data dump in the dump, it's strange why the compact section asks for the sep variable?

example js chart :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _ydata=JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($months) !!}');
    var _xdata=JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($monthCount) !!}');
</script>
```

Comment: I don't use `compact()` enough to know if you can combine it with an array like that (your error suggest you can't), but you shouldn't need to, just do `return view('dashboard.admins',  ['user' => $user, 'jumlah_user' => $jumlah_user, 'data' => $data, 'months' => $months, 'monthCount' => $monthCount] ));`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: _ydata is not defined
    at chart-area-demo.js:10:13
chart-bar-demo.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ydata is not defined
    at chart-bar-demo.js:10:13

data is not defined why ?

Comment: although not using compact, and directly calling the variable but the error above does not exist but the data for the graph does not appear in JS, why ? Is there something wrong with my js chart code?

Comment: Looks like it! Did you include this `<script>` _before_ any other dependent scripts? If `$month` and `$monthCount` are being passed forward properly, but you're getting a JS "Not Defined" error, then obviously your issue is with your JS code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var _ydata=JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($months) !!}');
 var _xdata=JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($monthCount) !!}');
</script>

Comment: I use js in the script also still the data does not appear?

Comment: Please stop posting code in the comments; it's hard to read when not formatted. If you need to make an adjustment, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73872731/edit). Also, you're only showing the JS where you define these `_ydata` and `_xdata` variables, but not where you're actually using them. That's what I mean when I say "make sure you're defining them before trying to use them"

Comment: solved, thanks, i use with data all chart
return view('dashboard.admins', ['data'=>$data,'months'=>$months,'monthCount'=>$monthCount])
            ->with(compact('user','jumlah_user'));

Comment: That... Ok... ‍♂️ If it works for you, then you go ahead and use that, but that is a silly solution; you're mixing syntax and approaches for no reason. `compact('user', 'jumlah_user')` generates `['user' => $user, 'jumlah_user' => $jumlah_user]`, so just using `['user' => $user, 'jumlah_user' => $jumlah_user, 'data' => $data, 'months' => $months, 'monthCount' => $monthCount]` or `compact('user', 'jumlah_user', 'months', 'monthCount')` is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass single varibles with array of variables inside compact method. You can do two step here for passing each varible to view.

Method 1 => you can pass each variable as comma separated list inside compact and get in front end by variable name

```
return view('dashboard.admins', compact('user','jumlah_user','data','months','monthCount' ));
```

Method 2 => You can pass a single variable as array of different variables like

```
$view_data['user'][]=$user;
$view_data['jumlah_user'][]=$jumlah_user;
$view_data['months'][]=$month;
$view_data['data'][]=$data;

return view('dashboard.admins', compact('view_data'));
```

And use as normal on front end by accessing variable name

```
{{ $user }} {{ $months }} {{ $jumlah_user }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do. Do not use `compact` as it cannot have an array as an argument. Instead you should pass all your data as an array which is broken down into the various variables when accessing it in your view file.

Adjust your code to this:

```
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
            $view_data['user'] = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $view_data['jumlah_user'] = User::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get()->count();

            $view_data['data'] = Verifikasi_tte::join('surat_ttes', 'surat_ttes.id', '=', 'verifikasi_ttes.surat_tte_id')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.user_id')
                ->join('jenis_surat_ttes', 'jenis_surat_ttes.id', '=', 'surat_ttes.jenis_surat_tte_id')->select('surat_ttes.id','surat_ttes.klasifikasi','surat_ttes.no_surat','surat_ttes.tgl_surat','surat_ttes.created_at',
                'jenis_surat_ttes.nama_jenis_surat','users.name','users.opd_id','verifikasi_ttes.status')
                ->get()->groupBy(function($data){
                return Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('M');
            });
    
            $view_data['months']=[];
            $view_data['monthCount']=[];
            foreach($view_data['data'] as $month => $values){
                $view_data['months'][]=$month;
                $view_data['monthCount'][]=count($values);
            }

            return view('dashboard.admins',  $view_data);
        }
```

Now in your view file. You can just reference to each variable as you wish like this:
`{{ $user }}` `{{ $months }}` `{{ $jumlah_user }}` etcetera

Comment: solved, thanks, i use with data all chart return view('dashboard.admins', ['data'=>$data,'months'=>$months,'monthCount'=>$monthCount]) ->with(compact('user','jumlah_user'));

Comment: @Innovin Just a heads up, please refrain from asking for upvotes/your answer to be accepted. If it warrants being upvoted/accepted, it will be (and this one does, although I'm not a huge fan of arrays  for variables, but it works). Those kinds of comments are unnecessary noise and should be avoided.